# Authentication system for a web service

Tags: authentication, validation

I am building a web service which i will be launching in near future. Service is more or less like online classifieds.

Now, i need to **build a mechanism to collect user's information, enough to trace him in case of any fraud with other users**. I can ask for nation ID card and things like that. But problem is that **how will i verify them and the person providing the information.**
So, i need suggestions for such system which could be used t authenticate users, so other users can trust them. And contact them freely knowing in case of any mishap authorities can get its information from our service.
For solution we must consider that our service will be free so if this process is costly, than their might be a mechanism to get that cost paid by users.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: How does PayPal do it? Or Ebay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how much verification you want. You can verify that the ID number entered matches the details supplied (assuming that whatever nation the ID card belongs to provides some sort of API to do this - lots of countries don't even have standard ID cards though), but all that proves is that the person entering the data knows both the card number and the details that are associated with it in the national store. If I stole your wallet, I can probably make a pretty good guess at that link - bound to be something (driver's licence, passport, etc.) with your full name and enough of your address to be able to get the rest from online services in there.

You can't verify that a specific person entered the details, nor that (with some exclusions, perhaps vehicles, buildings, and land) they own the thing they are offering for sale.

If your marketplace is for relatively low value items, verifying email addresses might be enough. For more expensive items, you might want to look at verifying bank account details - look at sites like Paypal for how this works. For high value items (houses, for example), you'd probably want some manual verification steps in the process - having a copy of identification documents made by a solicitor or similar. Depending on the country, there might be legal requirements for specific types of goods - cars might need to be recorded in specific ways and registration documents provided to a central database, say.

In general though, for a purely online process, all you can state is that someone who knew some details about a person entered them.

Comment: Actually our service will be more or less like online classfieds, where people see, oh that person has that thing or can do that thing, and he want to get it, but he cannot trust him to come to his house and do some service or to give something to him to get it fixed.
<br>So, i think what we can do is to involve some kind of security fees or anything like that and attach user's bank account to our system. And tell other users that we don't take responsibility of any fraud, but if contacted by authorities, we can provide this much of information to them.